# How to align vertices on a symmetrical mode

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling a Jaguar animal. How do I model the eyes?
Look at the front view. The left line of vertices isn't aligned right, the end shouldn't be touching the nose, I want it to be aligned exactly like the right line. How can I achieve this?
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47801 here's my file

Simply put, I want both eye loops to be aligned with the Jaguar's eyes.
Why did my reference photos disappear all of sudden?

Sorry, I'm new to **Blender**.
Should I use images that are perfectly aligned, where the front or side is aligned perfectly with my view? Will they make my modeling faster and easier? Or is any image fine? What do you guys suggest?

Comment: Can you please take a screenshot?

Comment: You can download my blender file, it has 2 reference images in it. I gave the link from pasteall.org

Comment: The reference images aren't there. You'll need to pack them into the .blend. To do this click _File_ -> _External Data_ -> _Pack All Into .blend_. Then upload your file again. And please consider using [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) instead of pasteall. Blend-Exchange offers permanent storage.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! If you're not used to how Stack Exchange sites work, understand that they are each a Q&A database. If your question only applies to your specific situation, other readers are unlikely to benefit from reading it. "Help with my model" is a really vague title. Half the users here are probably seeking help with their models. Perhaps "How to align vertices on a symmetrical model" would be a better title? Other users with similar questions can search and find yours. Speaking of which, have you searched to see if an answer exists already? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, animal modeling! My favourite! :D

From my experience (and I have modeled *many*), the most crucial aspect is aligning your reference images properly. I use the `Images as Planes` addon to create the images and then align the different views as well as possible. Only then I start modeling and it becomes decidedly easier.

Selection of good references is also important - don't use close-up shots, but rather zoomed ones, because they will have much less perspective distortion.

If you're interested, I made a video tutorial showing this process. It is still old blender (2.49), but the general concepts and workflow are still the same. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zufMhsMi7jE&list=PL_XAV9LtBOVwG1crtM4npRrGWzzf4a-Ib

Comment: Curious... is there a reason you use Images As Planes instead of enabling Background Images?

Comment: Yes. I can freely align the planes in any way, which is not possible with background images AFAIK. Plus I can have an unlimited number of them active at the same time.

Comment: I get what you mean. Sometimes there's an arbitrary angle you want to align to, and BG Images don't allow for arbitrary angles, except when oriented to the Camera. I've tried Images As Planes too, but I found that the inability to control the transparency, as well as the fact that switching to Wireframe Viewport Shading makes the image planes invisible made it impractical for me (I work in wireframe a lot). What I did find to be a good workaround was using Empties that are set to display as Images instead of Plain Axes, and adjusting the transparency as needed.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because the jaguar is slightly turned to the side, but the left line of vertices (your left ) near the nose, isn't aligned as I would like it to be.
If nobody could read that, because it was hard to paint good letters: (1) I want this, to be here. (2) But at the same time, not move this. Basically, I want to move the left (your left) part of my mesh, even more to the left, BUT without moving the the right (your right) side, which I don't know how to do. I want to post an image but I don't know how to on this website. [https://imgur.com/8AwJ4aq]

Comment: Either move your view so that the model is rotated until it matches the head on the photo, or just find a straight front view. Hint: google "jaguar portrait", or search for references on flickr.com.

Comment: Thank you HENDRIX. I have one question, on an object that has the mirror modifier, how do I move the right side of the model without moving the left? for example, on my model I want to have 2 lines of vertices to touch the nose(I created 2 lines that go down the face eventually touching the nostrils) one is touching the nostril, one isn't. Maybe it has to do with the angle that the jaguar is at, his head isn't straightly alligned with my view

Comment: If i move any line (it doesn't matter which) the other line moves too, that is a problem for me, I have to choose which line touches the nostril, it can't be both unless I find a way to move one side of the mesh but at the same time not move the other side.
Is there a way to move only one side of the mesh at a time?

Comment: I also want to move the whole mesh a little to the left, to match the jaguar's angle, I can't find any straight front or side view images. I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do it, I've used G and R but nothing seems to work, how do I do it? 
And, is doing this important? would it really make my modeling easier and faster? or is the way I'm doing it right now fine?

Comment: Keep the model symmetrical. If you want to keep using this reference image (and I don't recommend that), either rotate the mesh _object_ or your camera view until model and image are properly aligned

Comment: Ok, I rotated the the model.

Comment: Why don't you recommend using the reference image?

Comment: i have a question, will using images that aren't perfectly aligned be slower and harder? right now I'm modeling my model separate from the reference image, and it seems harder than If I were modeling it on the reference image, but maybe it's only because I'm a newbie in blender and this is my first ever model that I have ever worked on. I just probably have to learn how to model in general.